# Vertical equivalence arrow in the middle between two lines

Tags: align

I'm trying to link two statements standing on below the other with a vertical equivalence arrow in the middle of the line. But the arrow doesn't show up in the middle but on the right of the two equation. How can I get it in the middle?

[image: latex output]

```
\begin{align*} 
\forall (y_1, x_1), (y_2, x_2) \in \mathcal R_f^{-1}: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2 
\\ \Updownarrow \\ 
\forall (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in \mathcal R_f: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2. 
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `gather*` here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*} 
  \forall (y_1, x_1), (y_2, x_2) \in \mathcal R_f^{-1}: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2 \\
                                 \Updownarrow                                        \\
    \forall (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in \mathcal R_f: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2. 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly centered, but quite simple: Use `&` from the `align*` environment to set a center point for the alignment. The `\Updownarrow` then is right-aligned within the first of the two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\forall (y_1, x_1), (y_2, x_2) \in \mathcal R_f^{-1}&: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2 
\\ \Updownarrow \\ 
\forall (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in \mathcal R_f&: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2. 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

There exists a dedicated command in `mathtools` which looks nicer than a centred arrow in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & \forall (y_1, x_1), (y_2, x_2) \in \mathcal R_f^{-1}&: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2 \\
\ArrowBetweenLines
 & & \forall (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in \mathcal R_f&: y_1 = y_2 \implies x_1 = x_2.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm... for me, it looks not quite right. Is it a convention? I've never seen it before.

Comment: It's a convention among others. For me, it has the advantage to be immediately visible and without  any ambiguity: the equivalence is for formulæ as a whole, not for specific parts of them.